# Name of a meandering, snake-like plot

Tags: data-visualization, terminology

The source is [Nate Silver's blog](http://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2016-election-forecast/#stateorder) FiveThirtyEight, and appropriately labeled, "*The winding path to 270 electoral votes*:"

[image]

I looked up... predictably, "snake plot", returning a lot of DNA pictures...

---

I think @jwimberley nailed it: [Join, or Die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join,_or_Die)

[image]

Comment: This seems like the sort of infographic that's made more to look impressive than to be useful, in which case it's unlikely to have a name.

Comment: Some problems with this plot: Meaning of vertical position opaque. Meaning of curvedness/straightness of the 'snake' is opaque. Meaning of dashed vertical line is opaque. Meaning of color intensity confusing because of it's imperfect correlation with right/left position (yet Indiana is redder than its neighbors).

Comment: The dashed vertical line is not opaque: it's explicitly stated that this is the number of electoral votes needed to win the presidency.

Comment: It is stacked bar chart, made wavy, with presumably the length of the snake equal to the number of electoral votes. The order of the states is arbitrary, as in most stacked bar charts.

Comment: @Alexis The color is actually perfectly correlated with its LR position... it's a red-blue color palette mapping to the probability of outcome.  The leftmost things are bluest, and are most likely to go for D, while the rightmost things are reddest, and most likely to go for R.

Comment: @T3am5hark You are mistaken, if it were perfectly correlated, then Indiana would not be visibly and obviously *more* saturated red than its neighbors AK and Utah. Same for SD being *less* saturated than MS and Kentucky, etc.

Comment: @T3am5hark As to the vertical bar: "the number of electoral votes needed to win the presidency" is not obviously mapped onto the structure of this graph/the 'snake.'

Comment: @Alexis good point... it seems to hold for the L->R direction with blue, but not for the R->L with the red.  Not sure of the reason for this.

Comment: In the case of Utah, I think it's because that state effectively has a 3-way race in which Clinton and McMullin are in a dead heat. I'm less sure why the color gradients are skewed in other states.

Comment: Hillarious. Or not.

Comment: @NickCox You know, there is another one like this, but verticalized 90 degrees... Not so attractive... More like a commercial for a laxative... Anyway, this is one slow-moving river. Perhaps it is meant to portray the excruciating pain the world is feeling with this election cycle...

Comment: @NickCox I can't quite figure out how to work the old "there's skid-marks in front of the snake" punchline into this graph... but I am sure it's there somewhere.

Comment: Tom Lehrer (statistician, never quite finished his PhD thesis on the mode) really did say that satire was dead if Kissinger could get the Peace Prize. Equally I am not clear that this election leaves scope for humour. Declaration of interest: Not a US citizen. Concerned.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/dataisugly/

Comment: It's effectively a stacked bar chart as "infographic". It winds up and down rather than just left to right because it's *really long*, and your screen isn't. It says it's in order of "strength" for the candidates but it doesn't define what that "strength" actually is (it's not purely poll percentage, but it's highly correlated with it).

Comment: Great comment thread. I wonder if the non-perfect correlation of color with position could be a bug instead of a feature.

Comment: @amoeba I think it's deliberate. The mavens at fivethirtyeight will not have falied to notice that the colour depth is not in order; Alaska is consistently "out of place" for example, in a visually jarring way. It would be ludicrous if they failed to notice something that stands out every time you load the page. (Well, I guess it's possible they missed it but it would be an astonishing lapse.)

Comment: @Antoni it's probably ad hoc (as many media infographics are) but it undoubtedly has a number of precedents out there. I believe it is coded by someone on the staff, yes, I think it even says who somewhere on the site.

Comment: I think it's supposed to be reminiscent of the revolutionary war "Join, or Die" flag

Comment: It actually reminds me a bit of intestines, which seems somehow apt.

Comment: Known as Jejunum-Ileum-[cecum] chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They call it a **snake chart** according to this:

[image]

[image]

[image]